# php / ajax. It always appends the data in the same section, instead of taking into account the for and the clicked button

Tags: php, ajax

Currently I have the following table made with html

```
<table class="table table-dark table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td><?= $nombre?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Apellido</td>
        <td><?= $apellido?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><?= $email?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>DNI</td>
        <td><?= $dni?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Rol</td>
        <td><?= $rol?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php if($usuarios[$i]["IdRol"] == '2'){ ?>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                <!-- -->
                    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="hidden" id="dniOculto" name="dni" value="<?= $dni?>">
                        </div>
                        <!-- Button -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="ver"></label>
                          <div class="col-md-4">
                            <button id="ver" name="ver" class="btn btn-primary">Ver líneas</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>


                        <script type="text/javascript">

                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#ver").click(function(e){
                                e.preventDefault();    
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: 'adminVerLineas.php',
                                    // data: {
                                    //     tlf: $("#num").val(),
                                    //     idTarifa: $("#opcion").val()
                                    // },
                                    success: function(data) {

                                        $("#postInfo").append(data);

                                    }
                                });
                            });
                        });
                        </script>
                    <!-- -->

                    </fieldset>
                    </form>
                    <table class="table" id="postInfo" ></table> 
                </td>

            </tr>

        <?php } ?>



</table>
```

Point is that its printed multiple times because its printed with a for based on the results of a database. 
So its located inside this php for

```
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($usuarios); $i++){ //the table is there }
```

It basically prints all the user data, and in each table ive setup a button with ajax which should append new data just below the button.
The called script is as simple as this

```
<?php

echo "<tr>
<td style='color : white'>Número</td>
<td style='color : white'> 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color : white' >Minutos Gastados</td>
<td style='color : white' >1 / 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color : white' >Megas Gastados</td>
<td style='color : white' >1 / 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='color : white' >Tarifa</td>
<td style='color : white' >1</td>
</tr>";


?>
```

The point is that when I click the button, it always posts the data below the first table, but I have more tables with the same button, and no matter what button i press, it will always post the data below the first table, instead of below the clicked button.

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique, you shouldn't use the same ID in each row of the table. Use classes instead. And you shouldn't repeat the jQuery code in each row. Just bind to the class once, and use selectors relative to `$(this)` to refer to the elements in the same row.

Comment: The problem can be done if you follow @Barmar comment. Here I give you the example code https://jsfiddle.net/ngekoding/cu45L691/2/